# How to tell if NSPanel is no longer in view?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am using an NSPanel to show application stats. When the App Delegate calls computeStats, it then tries to check if the NSPanel isVisible. Now the NSPanel is not loaded at app start. It requires the user to turn it "on" from a command. This then shows the NSPanel.

```
-(IBAction)viewStats:(id)sender
{
    [self.statsPanel makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

Now, if the user closes the stats panel, the computeStats method checks to see if it is visible, and only if it is, it will then update the NSTextFields with the stats data.

```
-(void)computeStats
{
    if ([self.statsPanel isVisible])
    {
        [self.minLabel setDoubleValue:min];
        [self.medLabel setDoubleValue:med];
        [self.avgLabel setDoubleValue:avg];
        [self.maxLabel setDoubleValue:max];
    }
}
```

This however fails (crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS) **after** the user opens then closes the NSPanel. Its as if the panel is still visible, even after the user closed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
[self.statsPanel setReleasedWhenClosed:NO];
```

When first showing the stats panel.

Comment: This. Optionally, if your Panel is a NIB you can uncheck "Release when closed" in the attributes pane.